# How to interweave two arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm super confused with getting this to run, as nested loops are still a bit funny to me.

With the following two arrays:

```
let a = ['y','y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
```

How do I get it to print **one value from a**, and then **two values from z** after that so and so on?

```
'y',
'x',
'x',
'y',
'x',
'x',
'y',
'x',
'x'
```

If the values were instead:

```
let a = ['y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
```

It'd print:

```
'y',
'x',
'x',
'y',
'x',
'x',
'x'
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < z.length; j++) {
      console.log(z[j], z[j+1]);
    // break?
    }
}
```

Comment: your z array contain 5 element but in your output every y have 2 pair of x so correct this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
`
let a = ['y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
let j = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log(a[i]);
  for (j; j < z.length; j++) {
    console.log(z[j], z[j+1]);
    if(j % 2 == 1){
       break;
    }
  }
}`
```

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

I repair your loop:

```js
let a = ['y','y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log(a[i]);
  console.log(z[i*2], z[i*2+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use `do`/`while` loop. Use `shift()` to remove the first item.of an array

```js
let a = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'];
let z = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6'];

//Copy the array a and z
let aTemp = [...a]; 
let zTemp = [...z];

do {
  if (aTemp.length) console.log(aTemp.shift());
  if (zTemp.length) console.log(zTemp.shift());
  if (zTemp.length) console.log(zTemp.shift());
} while (aTemp.length || zTemp.length); //Loop while both the temp variables have elements
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let aIndex = 0, zIndex = 0;

 while(aIndex < a.length || zIndex < z.length) {
    console.log(
      a[aIndex++],
      z[zIndex++],
      z[zIndex++]
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is non destructive way of doing this

```
var pointer = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      var count = 0;
      console.log(a[i]);
      for (let j = pointer; j < z.length; j++) {    
        console.log(z[j]);
        count++;

        if(count == 2){
            count = 0;
            if(i == a.length-1) { continue; }else { pointer = j+1; break; }
        }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any `for` or `while` too! try this:

```js
let a = ['y','y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
console.log(
    [].concat.apply([], a.map(function(m, i){return [m].concat(z.slice(i*2, i*2+2));}))
);
```

Now you can join the result if you want like this:

```js
let a = ['y','y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
console.log(
    [].concat.apply([], a.map(function(m, i){return [m].concat(z.slice(i*2, i*2+2));})).join(",")
);
```

---

Or if you like `reduce` function, you can try this:

```js
let a = ['y','y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
console.log(
  a.reduce(function(ac, m, i){return ac.push.apply(ac, [m].concat(z.slice(i*2, i*2+2))), ac;}, [])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let c = j = 0;
z.map(function(item){
  if(c === 0 && a[j]){ console.log(a[j++]); }
  console.log(item);
  c = c > 0 ? 0 : c + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop at all. This can be done with a single loop with two counters.

```js
let a = ['y','y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
let result = [];

for(let i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length, j < z.length; i++, j+=2) {
 result.push(a[i], z[j], z[j+1]);
}

result = result.filter(item => item !== undefined);

console.log(result);
```

And here's the same code condensed to a one-liner core:

```js
let a = ['y','y','y'];
let z = ['x','x','x','x','x'];
let result = [];

for(let i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length, j < z.length; i++, j+=2) {
 result.push.apply(result, [a[i], z[j], z[j+1]].filter(m => m !== undefined));
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below code. I pushed your expected output result in to an array.

```
    let a = ['y','y'];
    let z = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'];
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var count = 0
      arr.push(a[i]);
      for (let j = i * 2; j < z.length; j++) {
        arr.push(z[j]);
        count++
        if (count > 1) {
            if (z[j+1] !== undefined && a[i+1] === undefined) {
            for (let k = j+1; k < z.length; k++) {
              arr.push(z[k])
            }
          }
        break;
        }
      }
    }
console.log(arr);
// ["y", "x", "x", "y", "x", "x", "x"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let a = ["y", "y", "y"];
let z = ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x"];

let y = a.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
  return [...acc, current, ...z.splice(0, a[index + 1] ? 2 : z.length)];
}, []);

console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

On every `a` array element you take previously accumulated array (initially `[]`), add `current` element and two elements from `z` if `a` has next element or the rest of `z` elements if `current` is the last element of `a`.
This unfortunately deletes elements from `z` in the process, so you might want to copy it before running it, i.e. you can wrap reduce in a function and pass a copy of `z`:

```js
let a = ["y", "y", "y"];
let z = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

const interweave = (arr1, arr2) => {
  return arr1.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
    return [
      ...acc,
      current,
      ...arr2.splice(0, arr1[index + 1] ? 2 : arr2.length)
    ];
  }, []);
};

console.log(interweave(a, [...z]));
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the length and calculate the interval/part lenght of the array for splicing and pushing to the result set.

```js
function getX(a, b) {
    var iA = Math.ceil(a.length / b.length),
        iB = Math.ceil(b.length / a.length),
        pA = 0,
        pB = 0,
        result = [];

    while (pA < a.length || pB < b.length) {
        result.push(
            ...a.slice(pA, pA += iA),
            ...b.slice(pB, pB += iB)
        );
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getX(['y','y','y'], ['x','x','x','x','x']).join(' '));
console.log(getX(['y','y'], ['x','x','x','x','x']).join(' '));
```